# Create a new object from own data using MendelianRandomization

Tags: r, r-s4

I need to create an object using my own data in Mendelian Randomization package in R. It instructs to create an 'MRInput' class object slot by slot using a function 'mr_input' followed by the example below.

```
    MRInputObject <- mr_input(bx = ldlc, 
                      bxse = ldlcse, 
                      by = chdlodds, 
                      byse = chdloddsse)
```

Would someone help me how I create an object of my own data using the mr_input function? 
Here's the link to the package description:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MendelianRandomization/vignettes/Vignette_MR.pdf

My data is in .txt format and looks like this;

```
    > dput(head(Sample_MR_data,10))

    structure(list(SNP = c("SNP_1", "SNP_2", "SNP_3", "SNP_4", "SNP_5", "SNP_6", "SNP_7", "SNP_8", "SNP_9", "SNP_10"), exposure.beta = c(-0.0062, -0.034, -0.0052, -0.028, 0.0076, 0.013, -0.0094, 0.0011, -0.024, -0.023), exposure.se = c(0.017, 0.016, 0.016, 0.016, 0.024, 0.02, 0.024, 0.02, 0.028, 0.018), outcome.beta = c(0.0026, 0.026, -0.023, -0.017, 0.012, 0.03, -0.0048, 0.026, -0.033,-0.0046),outcome.se = c(0.017, 0.03, 0.018, 0.037, 0.034, 0.02, 0.022, 0.034, 0.033, 0.017)),row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `new(...,"MRInput")`? or `MRInput(...)`(named `mr_input`)?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data for which a new `s4` object is to be made? Use `dput(head(my_data,10))` for instance.

Comment: I have pasted the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to have your data with the same `slots` as those defined by `mr_input`. Using `coursedata`. You can find available slots using `getSlots("MRInput")`.

```
mr_input(bx=coursedata$bx,bxse=coursedata$bxse,by=coursedata$by,
         byse=coursedata$byse)


 SNP exposure.beta exposure.se outcome.beta outcome.se
1 snp_1        0.1357      0.0676     -0.00855     0.0875
2 snp_2        0.4938      0.1015      0.25656     0.1325
3 snp_3        0.3476      0.1015      0.27784     0.1316
4 snp_4        0.0679      0.0980      0.17189     0.1265
```

Using the canonical way:

```
new("MRInput",betaX=1,betaY=2,snps="snp_10")
```

Result: Warning because I have not used all slots:

```
Vectors do not all have the same length.      SNP LDL-c.beta LDL-c.se CHD.beta CHD.se
1  snp_10          1    0.004        2 0.0286
2  snp_10          1    0.004        2 0.0300
3  snp_10          1    0.004        2 0.0310
4  snp_10          1    0.003        2 0.0243
5  snp_10          1    0.003        2 0.0222
6  snp_10          1    0.006        2 0.0667
```

Comment: my data is in .txt format and I don't know how to create an s4 object similar to 'MRInputObject' in the instructions so I could use it further in the analyses. I have pasted the data in my original question. I am new to R

Comment: Thank you so much, I have understood your instructions and made my object successfully :)

Comment: It certainly did :)